# Looking for details about the Ga. 11/7/2017 general election

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws

According to http://sos.ga.gov/index.php/elections/2017_elections_and_voter_registration_calendar, there's a general election on 11/7/2017. No other information is listed, not even which districts this election (or any other listed election) is relevant to.

I saw something on the news about needing to be registered to vote by November, but as a member of the 3rd district, are there any upcoming elections (in 2017) that I can even vote in?

I thought at first (due to misleading google search results) that this was about the upcoming election for state governor, a senator, sos, etc; but apparently that isn't until next year.

Comment: And now, thanks to this question, the tag "Georgia" now has one question for each major territory with that name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/Georgia_elections,_2017) there are several offices up for election on November 7 2017:

```
Georgia House of Representatives District 4 (General)
Georgia House of Representatives District 26 (General)
Georgia House of Representatives District 42 (General)
Georgia House of Representatives District 60 (General)
Georgia House of Representatives District 89 (General)
Georgia House of Representatives District 117 (General)
Georgia House of Representatives District 119 (General)
Georgia State Senate District 6 (General)
Georgia State Senate District 39 (General)
Atlanta Public Schools (General)
Atlanta (General)
```

Note that those districts are state districts not federal congressional districts, check to see if you are a member of one of them.  Registration ends October 10 2017.

Answer (score 1):

This is the date of your state's general election.  The calendar is just telling you when that date in general is, it is not referring to any specific elections.

However, the statute cited on that page gives you a list to start:

- The Governor
- Lieutenant Governor
- Secretary of State
- Attorney General
- State School Superintendent
- Commissioner of Insurance
- Commissioner of Agriculture
- Commissioner of Labor
- Members of Congress
- Justices of the Supreme Court
- Judges of the Court of Appeals
- Judges of the superior courts
- District attorneys
- Members of the General Assembly
- County officers

The statue states these offices

> shall be elected in the November election next preceding the
>   expiration of the term of office

Source:  http://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2010/title-21/chapter-2/article-1/21-2-9

Ballotopedia lists some specific offices that will be filled in this election, although the list may be incomplete.  It includes a U.S. House seat as well as state senators.

Source:  https://ballotpedia.org/Georgia_elections,_2017